# How to get the user account associated to the webdav request?

Tags: webdav, windows-explorer

When accessing a webdav using Windows Explorer (Not IE), the call is redirected thru the svchost.exe process (with webclnt.dll).

When i check get the pid of the process that is connected to the local port, i get the pid of the svchost.exe process.

How can i get the user account that the call was associated to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an LSP like komodia LSP, and in the WSAStartup function, you can user GetUserNameW() to retrieve the user account associated with the thread.